# Kotlin Android requests from activity

Tags: android, kotlin, request

I want to make a request via some library that implements stock exchange api and put the result into realm db. I am a bit new one into android programming and i cannot find how to synchronize these actions. I`ve been using Thread{*request*}.start to make all requests from activities, but now I need to wait the result. In other words, I want to synchronize these two operations:

```
                1.Thread { share.actualPrice = Web.getSharePrice(share.name) }.start()
                2.runBlocking {
                    launch {
                        val portfolio =
                            intent.getStringExtra("portfolio")
                                ?.let { repository.getPortfolio(it) }
                        if (portfolio != null) {
                            repository.insertShare(share, portfolio)
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Thank you!

I don`t really understand the coroutines and using them for requests.

Answer (score 0):

You don't mix threads and coroutines like that.  If you have a thread, you put all the code you want to run when the request is finished in the thread.  There's no reason to wait on the original thread.